# Enable alternate calendar systems in the date/time button of the tray

Tags: windows, windows-10

When clicking on the date / time in the system tray of the Windows taskbar, a calendar pops up.

How can I change this calendar to use a different calendar system (in my case, the Hebrew calendar)?

This can be changed for the Windows 10 Calendar app, but I want to change it for the tray icon calendar.

Comment: You can't (yet). MS has added [Lunar Calendar support for the Taskbar](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-lunar-calendar-taskbar/). This was done after user feedback so you need to feedback your own request to Microsoft.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've [done so](https://aka.ms/AA8qq3x). Should I put this link in a self-answer to this question?

Comment: Up to you. It's not really an answer though.